# Get Revit model as Autodesk.Revit.DB Document class using Desktop Connector

Tags: revit-api

I'm looking for a way (may not be possible) to get a Revit file from the Autodesk
Desktop Connector to a Document class so I won't have to use the cloud API's.

The code below doesn't compile but does represented the genral idea, any thoughts ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices;
using Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServicesTools;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Set up connection to the Autodesk Desktop Connector
            WebServiceManager serviceManager = WebServiceManager.GetServiceManager();
            string ticket = serviceManager.SecurityService.Authenticate();

            // Get the list of files in the Autodesk Desktop Connector
            File[] files = serviceManager.DocumentService.FindFiles(ticket, "*.rvt");

            // Open the first Revit file in the list
            Document doc = Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(files[0].path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access the Revit `Document` class from such an external context. To access it, you need to be in a valid Revit API context:

- [Use of the Revit API Requires a Valid Context](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/external-event-and-10-year-forum-anniversary.html#2)
- [Valid Revit API Context and External Events](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/11/document-session-id-api-context-and-external-events.html#3)

Such a context is either provided by running `Revit.exe` on your Windows desktop and installing an add-in implementing the requisite Revit API event handlers, or by making use of the Autodesk Platform Services APS (formerly Forge) [Design Automation API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/).

Comment: Great straight forward answer, I'll  focus my efforts towards the design automation api.